# angular 2 and cordova device on ready

Tags: angular, cordova

I have a Cordova app built in angular 2. I have created a custom plugin that goes in to the device retrieves some data then returns this to a page which, all works fine.

However, when this page in question runs at the start of the app opening, the device ready event has not triggered therefore the data is null (as expected) as angular has started before the device is ready.

How can i notify angular 2 that the device ready event has occurred? Usually i would create a Subject and Subscribe.

I'm thinking of doing this in the entry point of the app and use an emit() to notify areas in the app:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', deviceReady());
```

Is there any better options? I know in Angular 1 you would bootsrap the app but it works differently in v2.

UPDATE -----------------------------------------------

I went with the answer from n00dl3 and works great

But used this as my service:

```
declare var IPFinder, Windows, device;
@Injectable()
export class DeviceService {
  // contains the api's for each plugin used
  device: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private cordovaService: CordovaService) {
    this.deviceReadyEvent();
  }

  // when the device is ready
  deviceReadyEvent() {
    this.device = this.cordovaService.deviceReady.map(() => {
      console.log('DEVICE READY IN ANGULAR');

      // add plugins here
      let deviceAPI = {
        IPFinder: IPFinder,
        device: device
      };

      this.platformSpecific(deviceAPI);

      return deviceAPI;

    });
  }

  private platformSpecific(deviceAPI) {
    if (device.platform === 'windows') {
      deviceAPI['Windows'] = Windows;
    }
  }

}
```

Then i call it (requires in constructor private deviceService: DeviceService & zone) using:

```
   this.deviceService.device.subscribe((device) => {

      device.IPFinder.getIP((ips) => {
        // zone required to update view
        this.zone.run(() => {
          this.setIPAddress(ips);
        });
      }, (error) => {
        console.log('error', error);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Service that will handle cordova events with an Observable and map data from that `Observable` in other services. (I made one service by plugin for my personal case...)

In tis example I want to get platform informations using the [cordova-plugin-device](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/). You'll need to install type definitions: [@types/cordova-plugin-device](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/cordova-plugin-device).

**cordova.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class CordovaService {
    deviceReady: Observable<Event>;
    constructor() {
        this.deviceReady = Observable.fromEvent(document, "deviceready").publishReplay(1);
        (this.deviceReady as ConnectableObservable<Event>).connect();
    }
}
```

You need to `publishReplay(1)` and `connect()` for that particular event because it fires once and once device is ready any other listener will get called immediately :

> The deviceready event behaves somewhat differently from others. Any event handler registered after the deviceready event fires has its callback function called immediately.

**device.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class DeviceService{
    platform:Observable<any>;
    constructor(private cdv:CordovaService){
        this.platform = this.cdv.deviceReady.map(()=>device.platform);
    }

}
```

and in a random component :

```js
this.deviceService.platform.subscribe(platform=>console.log(platform));
```

If you perform actions that requires a callback (so basically any cordova native action call), you can create an observable using `Observable.create()`. Example with filesystem API:

**filesystem.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class FileSystemService {
    constructor(private cdv: CordovaService, private zone: NgZone) { }
    read(file: FileEntry, mode: "text" | "arrayBuffer" | "binaryString" | "dataURL" = "text") {
        return this.cdv.deviceReady.switchMap(() => Observable.create((observer) => {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onerror = evt => {
                this.zone.run(() => observer.error(evt));
            };
            reader.onloadend = evt => {
                this.zone.run(() => observer.next(evt));
            };
            switch (mode) {
                case "text":
                    reader.readAsText(file);
                    break;
                case "arrayBuffer":
                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                    break;
                case "binaryString":
                    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
                    break;
                case "dataURL":
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    break;
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

You might need to import `ngZone` because the callback will probably be run outside of the angular zone, avoiding some change detections.

Comment: It's looking good so far but i'm getting error for the connect(): Property 'connect' does not exist on type 'Observable<Event>' I'm not sure if an import i'm missing. Currently i just have import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

Comment: oh yes, sorry, that's because an `Observable<Event>` has no `connect`method, you have to make a type assertion to `ConnectableObservable<Event>` or declare it as so (I prefer type assertion because outer-world has no need to know it can call `connect()` on that observable). I edited.

Comment: That did the trick! Next i'm getting an error from this line: .map(()=>device.platform) where does 'device' come from?

Comment: well it's from [cordova-plugin-device](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/), you need to install type definitions [@types/cordova-plugin-device](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/cordova-plugin-device). But it was just an example, you don't actually need to use this plugin....

Comment: I thought so, just wanted to double check, but here is where one would implement the plugin references...will continue